# Is the TypeScript language specification document up to date?

Tags: typescript

On the Github repository for TypeScript, the pdf is 4 years old (TypeScript Language Specification version 1.8 january 2016), but the version of the source code is 3.7.5.

Is this document still valid and the numbers are not in sync, or has there been 4 years without adding new features to TypeScript and only correcting bugs?

Answer (score 11):

The language spec is out of date.  As discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711), this is not currently a priority for the language maintainers.

You can see the up-to-date documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html), including the new features in the language (there's been plenty of them since 1.8).