# What does <T = unknown> mean in a generic class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript-generics

In some code I am reading, I see a class declared thus:

```
export abstract class ClassName<T = unknown> implements InterfaceName { … }
```

I am familiar with unconstrained generics (`class C<T> {…`) and constrained generics (`class C<T extends S> {…`), but what does `= unknown` mean, and what effect does it have compared to no constraint at all?

Surely, absent an `extends`, code within the generic class must treat `T` as if it were `unknown` already?  And if `<T = S>` means to pin type `T` to exactly type `S` then why make it a generic at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default parameter type. It is type, that is resolved, when the type constructor is given without the type parameters.

Consider this class definition:

```
export class Class<T = unknown> { }
```

Then you can create instances either with explicit type for `T` or without.

```
const x = new Class()
const y = new Class<unknown>()
const z = new Class<number>()
```

Here, type of `x` and `y` will both be `Class<unknown>`, whereas `z` would be `Class<number>`. So it means, that declaring class with `<T = unknown>` is the same as `<T>`.

So for this particular case, it doesn't make much sense, but if you choose anything else than unknown, then it will serve as default type parameter.

Note, that it doesn't serve as constraint, that means that if you declare

```
export class ClassB<T = string> { }
```

you can still declare:

```
const z = new ClassB<number>()
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you.  Where is this documented?  Not [on the handbook page about generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), AFAICT.

Comment: see this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148566/is-the-typescript-language-specification-document-up-to-date apparently typescript unfortunately doesn't have a formal specification, therefore you only can learn from handbook/changelog/github issues of typescript compiler

Comment: A formal spec would be nice, but not as important as the basic documentation being more or less complete, which alas it is not.